# Error executing query via CDbCommand

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, yii, postgresql-8.4

I have tried this query.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT ('Kegiatan - ' || coalesce(e.nama,'')) caption, l.id_event id,'e'::text AS berita_type
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN lokasi_pengamatan l ON l.id_event=e.id_event
LEFT JOIN users_location u ON l.id_lokasi_pengamatan=u.id_lokasi_pengamatan
WHERE
1=1
AND l.status = TRUE
AND e.status = TRUE
AND e.e_deleted_at IS NULL
AND l.lp_deleted_at IS NULL
)t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(e.nama,'') || ' - ' || coalesce(l.nama,'') caption, l.id_lokasi_pengamatan id, 'lp'::text AS berita_type
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN lokasi_pengamatan l ON l.id_event=e.id_event
LEFT JOIN users_location u ON l.id_lokasi_pengamatan=u.id_lokasi_pengamatan
WHERE
1=1
AND l.status = TRUE
AND e.status = TRUE
AND e.e_deleted_at IS NULL
AND l.lp_deleted_at IS NULL
)t2
ORDER BY berita_type ASC, id DESC, caption ASC
```

the query OK when executed via Postgre Manager but raise an error when executed via `CDbCommand`.

```
SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block. The SQL statement executed was:
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: I've never heard of "Postgre Manager". Do you mean PgAdmin-III? Anyway, the problem isn't that query, it's some query you ran before it that caused an error. Google the error message to see what I mean.

Comment: @CraigRinger that's one of them, or `Navicat`

Comment: @CraigRinger Yap, the error is caused from previous query.

Answer (score 1):

You should flush yii database schema cache:

```
Yii::app()->cache->flush();
```